# get text from html including format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the text from my html and preserve the proper format just like how it looks like on a browser.

i want this

```
               CompanyName
              CompanyAddress
           Company Phone Number

       1  Item1   7.00   0%   7.00
       2  Item2   5.00   0%   5.00
                  TOTAL:         2
               SUBTOTAL:     12.00
                   CASH:     12.00
```

I'm getting this

```
                    CompanyName
                   CompanyAddress
                Company Phone Number

                   1  

                   Item1   

                  7.00   
                   0%   

                     7.00
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="printPreview" class="interprise-popover-container">
<div class="interprise-popover-header popover-header">
    <h1 class="title">Print Preview</h1>
    <a class="popover-btn left-popover-btn btn-Cancel">Cancel</a>
    <a class="popover-btn right-popover-btn btn-Done">Done</a>
</div>
<br class="clearfloat"/>
<div id="printPreviewBody" class="interprise-popover-content">
    <div id="print-area">
    <div id="print-header">
        <h4><%= Company %></h4>
        <h6><%= WarehouseAddress %></h6>
        <h6><%= WarehouseCity %>, <%= WarehouseState %> <%= WarehousePostalCode %></h6>
        <h6><%= PhoneNumber %></h6>
        <h6>www.fairysales.com</h6>
        <h5 style="margin-top: 5px;"><%= TransactionType %>#&nbsp;<%= InvoiceCode %></h5>
    </div>
    <div id="print-barcode" style="margin:0 auto; "></div>
    <span style="font-size: 12px;">Monday</span>
    <div>
        <table id="print-items" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right"> 1 </td>
                            <td align="left"> Item1<br></td>
                            <td align="right">12.00</td>
                            <td align="right">0%</td>
                            <td align="right"><div><abbr>12.00</abbr></div></td>
                          </tr>
                       </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="print-total">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

By the way i used

```
$("#print-header").text(); to extract the text from the div
```

**UPDATE: here is the jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/8yC5G/1/

What i want to achieve is actually the same as the result but in text format so i can pass it as string from javascript to objective c.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. If you want to preserve the HTML formatting, why not use `.html()`?

Comment: but i only neeed the text. see i'm getting the text from javascript then pass it to objective c via phonegap plugin and that text will be passed to my print sdk for printing i'm doing a receipt by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `$("#print-header").html();` should solve your problem.

See [$.text() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [$.html() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: yes i also tried that. but anyway how about the table i would like it to be printed just like what i want(code above) but i'm not getting it. any ideas?

Comment: You could also try `$("#print-header")[0].innerHTML`... I'm baffled as to why what you're doing isn't working though.

Comment: both of what you suggested works. but my concern right now is on table part. how would i get the text from it but preserve the format?

Comment: What exactly are you getting returned? All I see in your returned box above is the text itself. Show me the HTML you get back when you call either of the solutions?

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle. using $("#print-area")[0].innerHTML you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Since your html is inconsistent with what you stated you want, and what you where getting, I'll ASSUME you do not want the barcode, you do not want 'monday', you do not want the 'transaction-type'/'invoice-code' and lastly no 'www.fairysales.com'
I'll also assume that you want <%= WarehouseCity %>, <%= WarehouseState %> <%= WarehousePostalCode %> next to each-other.

But more importantly: I'm guessing you control this html-source and it's generation, since you used vars in your 'print-header'.
THEN I ASSUME you also have the var's that generate your 2 tables: 'print-items' and 'print-total' right?

Well if you have the vars.. and actually want to pass them to 'objective c', then.. you can control your data-format that you use to send this data to your objective c application for further tasks.

If you however you still want the equivalent of the rendered html text as a (mono-)spaced plain text (for let's say a text-only fall-back in the htm-email to the customer) as a input to your objective c, then you need to think some more about your data like in the old-school-day's: how much characters will each field have in worst case scenario? This is the amount of white-space characters you will then need to append/prepend (to simulate your align right/left from your table). This is not that hard.

Now let's say you DON'T have access to the vars that build the html sent to the browser..
Then you'll have to work on something to recursively parse your html-blocks fetching 'innerTEXT'/'textContent' that contain the data you need (it could also look at the table's cell's alignment) before you can end up with the above technique (dataformat/calculation/prepending/appending).

So.. do you control the var's?

Hope this helps!

*ps:I recommended a mono-spaced font, since.. how else are you going to align your data the way you posted 'what you want'?

ps2: I'm actually also wondering.. why `<div><abbr>12.00</abbr></div>` ??*

**UPDATE :** I fiddled around with your fiddle and built a function that does EXACTLY what you want. See [jsfiddle.net/8yC5G/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/8yC5G/3/embedded/result/)
The return function of the the function is still quite dirty and could use some optimizing. Maybe I'll fiddle some more. Note: built and tested in FF, uses 'textContent' instead of 'innerTEXT'.

**UPDATE2:** [jsfiddle.net/8yC5G/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/8yC5G/6/embedded/result/): new routine, cleaned up a bit, shorter and more reliable. Scales automatically :P